# Is Restler support https?

Tags: rest, https, restler

I'm currently going to develop a REST API. I found Restler seems to be a good choice. But I'm wondering if it supports HTTPS? If YES, is there any example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it supports it. This is setup on your webserver.

nginx: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

apache: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/ssl/ssl_howto.html

Comment: So that means it has nothing to do with the Restler or whatever library itself. It's only related to the web server? Thanks for your reply.
By the way, who click the down arrow for my question? Is this not a question although it maybe too simple for you?

Comment: @bagusflyer I didn't downvote your question, I just answered it for you. Thats right, rester is just like any other framework in that regard, it will run on either protocol, and any port you like. Good idea to just use https though with an API. Good luck on your project.

Comment: Thanks. I know you're not the one who downvoted. I just think down voting is not helpful at all.